# Grabbing select value using regular javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was working on a script that grabs the value from the selected option in a drop down select list and assigns it to an object. The only problem I'm having is that it's saying I have a null object.

The .js is as follows:

```
    var s = document.getElementById('mode');
alert(s.options[s.options.selectedIndex].value);
function selectValue(){

  yo.newSelect(s.options[s.options.selectedIndex].value);
  return true;
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
 <div id="text_editing">
       <form action="javascript:;" method="post" onsubmit="editHomePage()">
       <select name="CYD" id="mode" onchange="selectValue()">
        <option value="Home">Home</option>
        <option value="About">About</option>
        <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
       </select>
<textarea name="sexyText" row="500" col=500">    
</textarea>
<input value="submit" name="text_submit" type="submit" onclick="selectValue()">
       </form>
```

I'm just looking for a solution in plain js. I not interested in using jQuery for such a small site.

Comment: 1) On what browser are you testing this? - 2) NULL object is the result of the Alert box?

Comment: Chrome. The alert box doesn't pop up at all. I'm getting this info from firebug lite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your options have a value, you can simply write:

```
alert(s.value);
```

which will return the value of the first selected option (so not suitable for multiple selects with more than one selected).

Incidentally, from your listener you could do:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="selectValue(this)">
```

then in the function:

```
function selectValue(el) {
  alert(el.form.mode.value);
}
```

Comment: The first method you mentioned I did perviously on a different script but with numbers and it worked them. I might just do that. I tried using the other method you mentioned but it just told me 'form' was undefined. At which point I threw up my hands and made my values numbers like before.

Comment: All form controls in a form have a *form* property that references the form they are in. If they're not in a form, it won't have a useful value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like initially, none of the options are selected; therefore, `s.options[s.options.selectedIndex]` would be null when the page first loads.

I would recommend using the Firebug plugin for Firefox to step through your code; you can easily identify these kinds of issues using the debugger.

Comment: I actually have it for Chrome. I tried what you said to do, that is make one of the options `selected="selected"` by default but that didn't work out either.

Comment: Using firebug, you should be able to tell which object is null, and what the value of selectedIndex is

Comment: Yeah I checked out the DOM tab on in Firebug on both Chrome and Firefox, it was telling me that s was null. I didn't figure out a way to stuff the string value in it so I just made the value numbers and followed RobG's advice. Thanks to both of you!